vue3 with typescript automatic unpacking typing check error
vue3 with typescript automatic unpacking typing check error
this is class define
import { type DefaultOptionType } from 'ant-design-vue/es/select';
import { ref, type Ref } from 'vue';

interface Selector {
  kind: KindType | undefined;
  destination: string | undefined;
  selectOptions: Ref<DefaultOptionType[]>;
}

export class Policy {
  uuid: string;
  selector: Selector = {
    kind: void 0,
    destination: void 0,
    selectOptions: ref<DefaultOptionType[]>([])
  };
  constructor() {
    this.uuid = uuid();
  }
}

This works normally but in component

interface FormData {
  policies: Policy[];
}

const a = reactive<FormData>({
  policies: [new Policy()]
});

when I use
a.policies.push(new Policy())
I'm get an error:
Argument of type 'Policy' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ uuid: string; selector: { kind: KindType | undefined; destination: string | undefined; selectOptions: DefaultOptionType[]; }; ipblock: { ...; }; }'.ts-plugin(2345)
(alias) new Policy(): Policy
import Policy

only type check error
codesandbox
ant-design-vue is my Component lib

I guess you should make a sandbox for this. There's something wrong with your selector type

okay, I'm update

are you sure that DefaultOptionType is a valid type export from "ant-design-vue" ?

I even tried to reproduce your error on my local computer but failed. I couldn't find DefaultOptionType type. Without it, there's no error

yeah, I'm sure. I don't know why did ts not check type in codesandbox. This is nothing. You can declare other type. is only a certain type of array

When you initialize a.policies with [new Policy()], TypeScript infers the type of the policies array based on the Policy instance.
However, because you’re using Vue’s reactive function, the Policy instance is unwrapped and its reactive properties are exposed. This means that TypeScript sees the type of policies as an array of the unwrapped properties of Policy, not an array of Policy instances.
To fix this, you can explicitly declare the type of policies as Policy[]
Something like this should fix it.
const a = reactive({
  policies: [new Policy()] as Policy[]
});


Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't write the complete code. Actually I declare paradigm. I'm update the question.

Whether using policies: [new Policy()] as Policy[] or paradigm, an error is reported
